# Background Upload

Tags: iphone

I am looking for a direction on a background image upload on the iPhone, background meaning in my app while other interface items  are processing and views are changing.

I was thinking that there would be a way in the appDelegate to spawn a process to upload the file, then have a delegate return the status.

Has anyone seen an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

I plan on using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) in my app to handle communications to web servers in the background.